# Power BI dataset filter in Create Report mode

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to set **filter** on power bi report in **create mode**. I found the example to set the filter on dataset at report level, page level and visual level but the filter is not working when embed setting is for report creation (Create mode).

`Please find the below code which is for power bi report creation.`

```
var embedDiv = document.getElementById('embedDiv');

const iFilters: IBasicFilter = {
        $schema: 'http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic',
        filterType: FilterType.Basic,
        target: {
            column: 'COLUMN1',
            table: 'TABLE1'
        },
        operator: 'In',
        values: ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2'],
    };

const configuration = {
              'accessToken': 'ae...ex',
              'embedUrl': 'https://app.powerbi.com//reportEmbed?groupId=group_id',
              'datasetId': 'aex....mky'
              };

// The below line gives Create Object.
const embedObject = this.powerBIService.createReport(embedDiv, configuration );

embedObject.on('loaded', function(e){

// the below line gives error because setFilter is a method of Report instead of Create class.
          embedObject.setFilter([iFilter]);
});
```

Is any other way to filter the data when we load the dataset for creating the chart?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the filters run-time by calling `embedObject.setFilter([iFilter]);`, you can define the filter directly in the embedded configuration:

```
const configuration = {
    filters: [iFilter],                           <-- add this line
    'accessToken': 'ae...ex',
    'embedUrl': 'https://app.powerbi.com//reportEmbed?groupId=group_id',
    'datasetId': 'aex....mky'
};
```

Comment: Andrey, I tried the above code but It is not working for create mode. It works only for an existing report.